# Extended automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, normal-extension

Let $F < E < K$ be a tower of field extensions and assume $K$ is a normal extension over $F$. It's well-known that any embedding in $E$ fixing $F$ can be extended to an isomorphism in $K$. One question raised in my mind is that "Can all automorphisms of $F$ be extended to an automorphism of $K$?". The answer is obviously no, for example, the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ is normal over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, but there isomorphism sending $\sqrt{2} \to -\sqrt{2}$ can not be extended. So my question is under what condition we have all automorphisms of $F$ can be extended to an automorphism of its normal extension?

Any helps would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Let $k<F<K$ be a tower of field extensions
and $K$ be a normal extension over $F$.
I think that every automorphism of field $F$ over $k$ can be extended
to an automorphism of field $K$ if and only if $K$ is a normal extension over $k$.